# Absolutely positioned elements have no height. What does it mean?

Tags: css, css-position

Hy,

I read on the web that absolutely positioned elements have no height. Can someone explain this in a simple way and possible illustrate it with an example.

Comment: it would be useful if you posted a link to where you read this.

Comment: Actually it should have the height of its content.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a bit confused. You probably heard that **elements which contain only absolutely positioned elements have no height**. That makes more sense.

An absolutely positioned element, like any element, would have the height of it's content, unless specified otherwise with `height` or `min-height`.

An element containing only absolutely (or floated) positioned elements have no height, because their content (a.k.a. the positioned elements) are taken out of the document's flow. Which means, they aren't rendered along the render tree of the document, where inline elements stack horizontally, and block elements are stacked vertically, but are rendered on an absolute position, relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. Because of that, their size doesn't count towards the parent's height.